# Is correct and natural to say "pick someone up to the airport" meaning to go to the person's place and bring them to the airport?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *pick someone up to the airport* meaning to go to the person's place and bring them to the airport? For example:

> I'm free tomorrow, so I can **pick** you **up** **to** the airport.

If it sounds off, what would a native English speaker say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can only pick someone up at a location where they already are. You should be able to replace "pick you up" with "allow you to get in my car" and have it still make sense.

A better way of saying this would be "bring you to the airport", "take you to the airport", "pick you up and take you to the airport", or even just "pick you up" if it's clear enough from the context that you will then bring them to the airport.

Comment: In addition, the idiomatic "I can run you to the airport", though more colloquial, carries the same meaning.

Comment: Or 'give you a lift to the airport'.